# query for sum balance for each customer

Tags: sql-server, inner-join

I have a 2 tables Cust_info and Payment

## Cust_info

```
cust_id,
f_name,
l_name
```

## Payment

```
cust_id,
c_date,
balance
```

now i want to getting sum of balance for each customers if their balance grater than 0 .
i use this query :

```
 SELECT payment.cust_id AS C_ID, 
        Sum(payment.balance) AS nBalance, 
        cust_info.f_name, 
        cust_info.l_name 
 FROM cust_info 
 INNER JOIN payment ON cust_info.cust_id = payment.cust_id 
 GROUP BY cust_info.f_name, cust_info.l_name 
 HAVING Sum(payment.balance)>0
```

this query just returns `cust_id`,while i want output to be like this:

```
 1 - Mick - Anderson - 120
```

Comment: Provide some sample data or create a fiddle please

Comment: by the looks of it you are getting first name and last name. Provide sample data plz.

Comment: Also you query has error, you haven't included cust_id in group by ,but used it without aggregate function in select. It is compile time error!

Comment: it is strange it works, because you need to add `payment.cust_id` into Grouping...

Comment: Are you sure that the tag on your question `sql-server` is correct? From the behavior I would bet you are on MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

### **QUERY**

```
SELECT     payment.cust_id AS C_ID, 
           SUM(payment.balance) AS nBalance, 
           cust_info.f_name, 
           cust_info.l_name 
FROM       cust_info 
INNER JOIN payment 
ON         cust_info.cust_id = payment.cust_id 
GROUP BY   Payment.cust_id, cust_info.f_name, cust_info.l_name 
HAVING     (SUM(payment.balance)>0)
```

### **[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/39ee4/1)**

Added the grouping of payment.cust_id

Comment: Since the question is about SQLServer take a look : [Your fiddle on SQLServer](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/95812/1)

Comment: thank's all ,specially Adimeus,  i could get my goal with above code , But if i use "where cust_id=" & Val(txtcustid.text) & " to filter customers ,where can i put this clause ? thanks again